# Can't unarchive custom Object with NSKeyedUnarchiver in AR Multiuser

Tags: swift, arkit, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I'm using `MultipeerConnectivity` to share `SCNNodes` position in a multiuser `AR session`. 
When I archive (with `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: someARNode, requiringSecureCoding: true)` ) 
And unarchive (with `if let node = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass:SCNNode.self, from: data) {`)

Everything works fine, but now I'm trying to send a custom Object like this:

```
struct ARUser: Codable {
    var idUser : String
    var position: [Double]
}
```

When I try to unarchive the object received  with the `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject` it let me error.

```
if let node = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass:ARUser.self, from: data) {...}
```

I get the syntax error: `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'ofClass:from:', expected 'ofClasses:from:')`

But if I change the  function as suggested by the compiler:

```
 if let node = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses:[ARUser.self], from: data) {..}
```

I get the next syntax error: `Cannot convert value of type 'ARUser.Type' to expected element type 'AnyObject.Type'`
So, the question here is, what's the correct way to unarchive custom Objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since here you use `Codable`

```
struct ARUser: Codable {
```

Then

```
do {
   let dataToObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ARUser.self,from:data)
   let objectToData = try JSONEncoder().encode(dataToObject)
}
catch { 
   print(error)
}
```

`NSKeyedUnarchiver` is an old Objective-C stuff